# Reading an External json data

Tags: json

My script is looking at json files created on the server and retrieved using

//this is the code that gets the JSON file

```
jQuery.get(link,data)
```

Alerting out 'data' shows the json text as valid:

```
{"menu":[{"link":"../chapter-1/index.html","title":"Chapter 1", "dl": "chapter-1"}
```

I try and parse the returned 'data' variable

obj = JSON.parse(data);

So that I can loop through it and do my additional tasks.
When I try and JSON.parse(data) it fails

```
//The loop
  for (i = 0; i < obj.menu.length; i++) {
      console.log(obj.menu[i].dl);
      download_packet(obj.menu[i].dl, i);
    }
```

When I add the json manually

```
 obj = JSON.parse('{"menu":[{"link":"../chapter-1/index.html","title":"Chapter 1", "dl": "chapter-1"}]}');
```

It works.

I have tried to convert to string etc.

Anyone know what I am stuffing up? - There are no error messages in the console.

This is the whole snippet:

```
function download_items(link) {

  jQuery.get(link, function(data) {
    var obj = data;
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < obj.menu.length; i++) {
      console.log(obj.menu[i].dl);
    } 
  });
}
```

Comment: "Anyone know what I am stuffing up?" Not for certain, because you haven't included any of the relevant code, or error messages.

Comment: One call  is parsing a file, the other call a string.

Answer (score 0):

@Malcolm Mclean - put me on the right track.I converted my object to string then parsed it and it worked. A bit inefficient but its working.

Thanks Mal!

The JSON had to be parsed correctly:

```
  jQuery.get(link, function(data) {
      var obj = String(json_object);
      obj = JSON.parse(json_object);
}
```